# regex to check if it root dir of url, "", "/", "/index.php"

Tags: javascript, regex

If I am getting the url in javascript through `window.location.href`, how can I check if I am somewhere other than the root directory based on the url string I just got. With a regex.

If the url string is "https://stackoverflow.com" and I am splitting by that (protocol+domain+tld), I want the regex to match:

- Nothing, ""
- Whitespace "/\s+"
- Forward slash "/"
- Index.php "/index.php"

But not "/questions", "/questions/ask", or an index.php or any file in a directory other than the root of the website like "questions/ask/index.php"

Comment: @chris85 Because I am doing something on the client side based on the url. The site is built on a php framework, hence index.php, but what I am doing needs to happen on the client side in js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will match your requirements.

```
^(|\/(?:index\.php)?|\s+)$
```

`^$` are anchors requiring a full string match. (`^` is leading, `$` is ending)
 `()` is a grouping
 `|` separates a valid possible match. The `?:` is a non-capture group (actually both groups could be non-capture groups). 
 We simplified a alteration by using the `index.php` optional (the trailing `?` makes the group optional).
`\s+` is at least one whitespace.
 and leading `|` allowed for nothing to be present.

It also could be written as:

```
^(?:|\/|\/index\.php|\s+|)$
```

Functional JS Usage:

```
var url = '',
    regex = /^(?:|\/|\/index\.php|\s+|)$/;
if(url.match(regex)) {
    console.log('TRUE');
} else{
    console.log('FALSE');
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lksghj4h/

Comment: Hmmm this makes complete sense, but when I try it in this site (Regexr.com) and in my code, inside an '.indexOf()', it doesn't match? Unlike in the link you posted. Here's the exact line: `url_arr.indexOf(/^(|\/(?:index\.php)?|\s+|)$/g)>-1`. It is evaluating to false when url_arr is ["", "/"]

Comment: I'm not much of a JS'r but shouldn't it be `match`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lksghj4h/

Comment: It can be either, regexp is supposed to work in .replace() and .indexOf() too. Anyway, thanks for the help!